# How to search all directories? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I know how to search a directory for a file(s) using `NSFileManager`. But I want to search all directories in iphone to find files with some extension (let's say .txt). How can I do that?

Comment: You want to search directories belonging to other apps too ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim Yes, for example if I want to access the files received via shareIt app then can I access it?

Comment: @AbidMehmood, no, that is what sandboxing do. AFAIK, at max you can use App groups, but it still won't do the one you wants. https://medium.com/@dinesh.kachhot/different-ways-to-share-data-between-apps-de75a0a46d4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that an app can access are those in the app's sandbox. This means you can access only those files that originated(directly or indirectly) from your app. Complete unrestricted access to the iOS file system is not possible as of now.

However I think it is worth noting that iOS 11 has introduced some changes that do allow you to view the document directories of other apps. This is possible only if those apps have made their documents directory public using the 'UISupportsDocumentBrowser'key in their info.plist. Again this depends on how the other apps are coded and might not be of help in your case.

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5244-document-based-apps-tutorial-getting-started